# How to get device id in a onRecive function

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, device

im trying to get the device id inside a onRecive (which is inside broadcastreceiver) but the only way i found is to use this code:

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)myActivity.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
device_id = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

but here i am not in an Activity. so how can i get the device id?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on onReceive then you have a Context.
If you have a context then you can call getSystemService and do the same thing as here

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
   public class PhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        device_id = tManager.getDeviceId();
        }
        }
```